# 502 bad gateway in express with serverless framework

Tags: express, aws-serverless

I am using Express as backend integrated in AWS Serverless framework.
API works fine most of the time but sometimes it sends 502 Bad gateway error in all the api's and I am not able to access any api's. It will be fine after roughly 1 hour.Kindly help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using a Lambda function?

Comment: yes ,i am using lamda function using proxy integration

Comment: Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error. How do i fix this issue?